# Error resolving images when applying both LessBundle & CssRewriteUrlTransform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, less, bundle

I am using bootstrap less in my MVC application.
To bundle and minify less, I use LessBundle (https://github.com/scott-xu/System.Web.Optimization.Less)

```
var bundle = new LessBundle("~/css/home").Include(
            "~/_globalresources/Css/language.less");
```

LessBundle is working but having a problem to resolve image urls in CSS. All image urls are not correct. So, I apply CssRewriteUrlTransform in this case but fail. All image urls are also not correct.

```
var bundle = new LessBundle("~/css/home").Include(
            "~/_globalresources/Css/language.less", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

I try to use StyleBundle instead of LessBundle to recheck CssRewriteUrlTransform and all image urls are resolved well.

```
var bundle = new StyleBundle("~/css/home").Include(
                "~/_globalresources/Css/language.less", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
```

I think, using both LessBundle and CssRewriteUrlTransform give an incorrect result.

Please help me to resolve my problem to archive my purpose: bundle less & resolve image urls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. Download LessTransform and fix it like this:

```
public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse bundle)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            if (bundle == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bundle");
            }

            context.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetLastModifiedFromFileDependencies();

            var lessParser = new Parser();
            var lessEngine = this.CreateLessEngine(lessParser);

            var content = new StringBuilder(bundle.Content.Length);

            var bundleFiles = new List<BundleFile>();

            foreach (var bundleFile in bundle.Files)
            {
                bundleFiles.Add(bundleFile);
                var filePath = bundleFile.IncludedVirtualPath;
                filePath = filePath.Replace('\\', '/');
                if (filePath.StartsWith("~"))
                {
                    filePath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(filePath);
                }

                if (filePath.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filePath);
                }

                this.SetCurrentFilePath(lessParser, filePath);
                var source = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                var transformContent = lessEngine.TransformToCss(source, filePath);
                foreach (var transform in bundleFile.Transforms)
                {
                    transformContent = transform.Process(bundleFile.IncludedVirtualPath, transformContent);
                }

                content.Append(transformContent);
                content.AppendLine();

                bundleFiles.AddRange(this.GetFileDependencies(lessParser, bundleFile.VirtualFile));
            }

            if (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations)
            {
                // include imports in bundle files to register cache dependencies
                bundle.Files = bundleFiles.Distinct();
            }

            bundle.ContentType = "text/css";
            bundle.Content = content.ToString();
        }
```

Resolving images works well.

Comment: It looks like a commit has since been made to the System.Web.Optimization.Less project to fix this problem